# How to get a direct link to a post on MeWe?

Tags: links, sharing

I want to link to a particular post on MeWe,

With fb, for example, I can get the link by right-clicking on the date, and copy to clipboard.

I can't find it on Mewe.
Clearly, mewe has a post ID, internally, otherwise they wouldn't be able to share it among other users.
It just need to be

a) visible, accessible, copy-able
b) lead to / show that post.

Or Is it intentional? mewe don't want to get its content linked, indexed or accessed from the outside world?

Comment: The posts do have an ID in the source when it displays a single post in a popup but I have not found any simple way to get MeWe to display the post on demand even in a popup window though that should be possible for some HTML wizard.  It can be searched for as   >>>>data-postid=<<<<

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite sure you can't do this (I've tried multiple ways) and I think it's intentional -- so that MeWe doesn't have to take down copyrighted videos you might put up because it doesn't know where they are. On the plus side, you don't get hassled for every song excerpt or video clip you put up, like you do on Facebook. But on the downside, you can't reference anything again in the future. This is a huge shortcoming of MeWe's, in my view.